# Decoding Byte Array to String

Tags: python, utf-8, hex, xbee

I'm interacting with an XBEE RF chip and want to decode it's incoming source address from a byte array to a string. The manufacturer's software does this already but I need to handle this in my own custom program. So

Received Address: b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00Aga\xf8'

Address (Decoded by Manufacturer): 00 13 A2 00 41 67 61 F8

I have been trying to decode this using address.decode('utf-8') but always receive a UnicodeDecodeError at \xa2 as an invalid start byte. I also need to know how to convert from the decoded version back to the byte array for sending messages back down the network.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Python 3.5 and higher, `bytes` (and some other `bytes`-like types) have [a `hex` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex), so you can just do:

```
b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00Aga\xf8'.hex()
```

to get:

```
'0013a200416761f8'
```

You can call `.upper()` on the result if case is important.

On 3.4 and earlier, `import binascii`, then use [the `hexlify` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
binascii.hexlify(b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00Aga\xf8')
```

to get the same result.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfect. For anyone else that follows this, to return from the hex format to the original bytes, I used bytes.fromhex(hex_output)